Is it possible to transform any invertible tridiagonal 2×2 block non-Hermitian matrix into a Hermitian matrix through a similarity transformation?
For any nth-invertible tridiagonal non-Hermitian matrix which consist of 2×2 blocks, and its diagonal elements are 0. Is it possible to transform it into a Hermitian matrix through a similarity transformation?
I have proved the nth-tridiagonal Hermitian matrix which consist of 2×2 blocks can be transformed into a non-Hermitian matrix, but haven't come up with a good method to prove the sufficient condition that nth-invertible tridiagonal non-Hermitian matrix which consist of 2×2 blocks can be transformed into a Hermitian matrix.

What does 3-row 2×2 block mean? Also, what did you try?

sorry, I made a mistake before, I try to solve a question in a engineering project

Please specify what you're asking. E.g., every 2x2 matrix is obviously tridiagonal. Or are you talking about an arbitrary $n \times n$-matrix which consists of 2x2 blocks? Also what have you tried yourself?

thanks for your suggestions
